# Python Scrapy - Trying to get JSON response from RESTful API

Tags: python, json, rest, scrapy

I want to get a JSON response from a RESTful API that I query. I put the URL in but all I get is a HTML response instead of JSON. It would be nice if I could get the JSON response straight up, without having to parse all the HTML. Is there a way to do this?

Note: When I put the URL in a browser, it gives me the HTML site with the JSON data in a pretty, collapsible format. When I send a GET request using the Python requests module, it gives me JSON data. How do I achieve the same thing in Scrapy?

Answer (score 0):

Open the JSON file in your browser, right-click it, and select "Inspect". See which tags include it; it can be in `<body>` directly or another tag.

Let's assume it is in a `<script>` tag; here is the code. (It would help much if you send us a sample page.)

```
import ast

# Scrapy code here

text = response.xpath('//script/text()').extract_first()
text = text.strip()
text = ast.literal_eval(text)

value = text.get("key")
```

1- Extract the JSON part between `<script>` tags (or whatever tags enclose it).

2- Use strip to remove extra spaces.

3- Use ast.literal_eval to convert unicode to dictionary.

4- Use get(key) to extract what you want to extract from the dictionary.

Note: You can combine several steps into one, but I separated them for the purpose of explaining.

Here I used the regular dictionary get() but if you want to use the json library, you have to import it and then use the dumps() function to create a JSON formatted string from the dictionary and continue from here.